# Choose the right Database for IoT

Tags: sql, database, nosql, storage

I'm wondering if someone in the community could help me to choose the right database for my use case. I have IoT data also, I expect to have about 2000(min) or 20,000(max) lines per hour. Which database is right for me?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're glad you're here. Unfortunately, your question doesn't fit the guidelines for questions on this site. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Questions asking for recommendations of tools are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Performance = Speedy/Generous Hardware.

Any modern db engine would be able to handle 99.9% of today's data crunching needs. You would only decide between the different ones based on the data structure of what you are collecting. NoSql? RDBMS? Hybrid? Mixed?

There's heaps of comparison documents all over the net.

It all depends on your use case. And you have it in your hands :)

Answer (score 0):

People using solr db, Cassandra for IoT. You can use it with a Queue mechanism like RabitMQ if needed.
but if we can take the latest data into the RDMS is very easy to use.
Ex: GPS data. The latest vehicle information will keep inside an RDMS and keep the old data inside a Document base will help us for easy access.